# Cm12.1 Thinks My Apps Storage Is 1Gb Where It Should Be 3Gb

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, partitions

Hello and please bear with me, I did read the insufficient-memory tag and other related posts and couldn't find something that seems to explain my particular problem.

In my device I get "Storage space is running out" which I'm sure is a very common complaint here. But the odd thing about it is that I get very contradicting info when I analyse my storage and everything I tried has failed, so it's starting to drive me catatonic.

The inbuilt storage app says:
Total space: 2.95GB (Available 267 MB).
Apps (app data and media content): 2.51 GB
Cached Data: 42.71 MB

My data analyser app says:
External storage: 16.89 GB free. 6.58GB occupied
Sdcard1: 17.16 GB free. 12.55 GB occupied
System: 382 MB free. 626 MB occupied

So am I correct that phone things my system partition should be 3GB but in reality it is only 1GB? The warning comes at 10% so I am guessing when I reach 300MB I start getting the warning, because some part of my phone thinks that system storage should be 3GB. But in reality the total available space is 1GB, which is very contradicting.

I have 10 apps on internal storage and 100 on SD card. Cache is cleared. No log files, no junk to clean. I have absolutely no space left and I can't see why.

The only explanation is that I have corrupt partitions and that phone is only using 1GB instead of 3GB. (Frankly with 64GB phone, 3GB for apps is a complete joke, so you can imagine 1GB makes the phone completely unusable). Basically I suspect all the numbers are bogus.

I didn't have this issues with CM11 so I am guessing something got messed up while upgrading to CM12.1

I am so fed up with this I will probably soon repartition the phone or switch to unified storage, but before going down that route, I want to see if anyone here understands what on earth is going on here?

[image]
[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: I think there is some confusion between `/data` and `/system` going on here, please analyse more and clarify.

Comment: Yeah it's not clear what each app is measuring, to be honest, and maybe that's what's causing all the confusion. 
My /data directory is 3.8GB but I can't find what could be deletable in there. There's no logs or cache files I think that I could clear...

Comment: You could try uninstalling some apps to see if they have any effect. Also, look around to see if the Dalvik-cache is up to something. You could try using this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo , and this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).

Comment: I uploaded the picture of DiskInfo and DiskUsage.
It appears that the Data directory is full, and 1.5GB is taken up by Dalvik cache. I had previously tied to wipe dalvik cache via TWRP and it made no difference, so is there another way to clear it?

Comment: After I wipe the dalvik cache, the phone spends about 30 minutes rebuilding it during which time all apps appear grayed out. After those 30 minutes the dalvik cache is again 1.5Gigs and I'm out of memory again.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Mystery solved: The apps that are stored on the SD card, were still occupying the data space in the internal storage. I never thought that'd be the case, otherwise what's the point of moving an app?

Comment: did you clear your cache and dalvik because the couple times i did a "dirty flash" i had to reflash because i had no space for apps